# Chain complexes indexed over measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$: Towards a measurable notion of Euler Characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, measure-theory, homological-algebra, model-categories

I have for a while tried to generalize the notion of a chain complex in a way to obtain a "continuous" or at least "measurable" notion of Euler Characteristic.

I have come up with the following definition:

Let $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set so that

**A.** $x\in M\Rightarrow x+1\in M$.

For every $x\in M$ let $P_{x}$ be an Abelian group or $R$-module for some ring $R$, and assume that $P_{x}$ is endowed with a $\Sigma$-algebra. For instance, $P_{x}$ might be a topological group or Lie group and the $\Sigma$-algebra is the Borel algebra associated to that topology. Then $P=\bigoplus_{x\in M}P_{x}$ is endowed with a $\Sigma$-algebra too.

Assume that for every two $x,y\in M$ so that $x\leq y$ there exists a morphism $d_{x,y}:P_{x}\longrightarrow P_{y}$ so that:

**B.** $d_{x,x}=\operatorname{id}_{P_{x}}$.

**C.** If $x\leq y\leq z$ and all three are in $M$ then $d_{x,z}=d_{y,z}\circ d_{x,y}$.

**D.** $d_{x,x+2}=0$.

**E.** For any two $x\leq y$ that are in $M$ and any $p\in P_{x}$, the map
\begin{equation*}
M\longrightarrow P\text{, }z\longmapsto d_{x,z}(p)
\end{equation*}
is a measurable map.

Obviously, if $M=\mathbb{Z}$ or a subset thereof this is - irrespective of the $\Sigma$-Algebra on the groups $P_{x}$ - just the definition of a chain complex. But I wonder if meaningful such complexes exist when $M\neq\mathbb{Z}$.